# Azure servicebus exception on load

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-aks

On production, noticing below error messages quite frequently on Azure service bus processor. What would be the reason? can't able to replicate it on lower environment

```
MessageReceiver error (Action=Complete, ClientId=MessageReceiver1topicname/Subscriptions/subscriptionname, EntityPath=topicname/Subscriptions/subscriptionname, Endpoint=ex.servicebus.windows.net)


Message processing error (Action=Complete, ClientId=MessageReceiver1topicname/Subscriptions/subscriptionname, EntityPath=topicname/Subscriptions/subscriptionname, Endpoint=ex.servicebus.windows.net)
```

Where the processor is AKS hosted, servicetrigger based Azure function based processor

SDK vesrion: "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.2"

Comment: Have your tried to increase the value for `maxAutoRenewDuration` under `sessionHandlerOptions` in host.json, may be your production work takes more time than in lower env.

Comment: You can try the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Verify the connection to the Azure Service Bus endpoint.
2. Check the credentials being used to connect to the Service Bus endpoint.
3. Ensure that the entity path is correct.
4. Monitor the usage of Azure Service Bus to ensure it does not exceed the quotas.
5. Review the logs of your Azure Functions to look for any exceptions that could be causing the error.